# ORA-01722: invalid number when executing query from VB.NET but not SQL Developer

Tags: sql, vb.net, oracle

I have the following code in a VB.NET application which populates a datatable:

```
sql = "SELECT *
       FROM REQUESTS
       WHERE VAL IN ( :pValList ) 
       AND STATUS NOT IN (0, 2, 9, 10)"

da = New OracleDataAdapter(sql, conn)
da.SelectCommand.BindByName = True
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("pValList", pValList))
da.Fill(dsData, "RequestHistory")
```

However, I'm getting the invalid number error caused by this line:

`WHERE VAL IN ( :pValList )`

`ValList` is actually a string such as `12566, 13234, 244555` however the string is constructed as valid SQL and if I take that string and run it directly in SQL Developer is returns without issue. Additionally, if I remove the parameter from my VB.NET code and use the same values but hard-coded it works correctly.

I have code elsewhere which references the same table and column which does not cause any issues, e.g.:

```
SELECT *
FROM REQUESTS
WHERE VAL = :pVal
```

What is VB.NET (or ODP.NET) doing to the parameter that causes it be fed in as an "invalid number"?

Comment: a list of number in sql is not in double quote (is not a string)

Comment: You would need to pass an OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray. Even with that, you can't just use an IN like that, it'll have to be from another select. If it's just coma and numbers, you could split your string before doing the IN

Comment: I think you'd have an easier time parsing it as a string, ie `WHERE instr(:pValList || ', ', to_char(val, '999999') || ', ') > 0`

Comment: @scaisEdge That is correct, a slight copy error on my part. The string isn't parsed in this that, it's displayed like that in the Locales window however.

Comment: @the_lotus would you mind writing some psuedo-code? I don't quite understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong  space after the param name  `"pValList "`

```
sql = "SELECT *
   FROM REQUESTS
   WHERE VAL IN ( :pValList ) 
   AND STATUS NOT IN (0, 2, 9, 10)"

da = New OracleDataAdapter(sql, conn)
da.SelectCommand.BindByName = True
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("pValList", pValList))
da.Fill(dsData, "RequestHistory")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just because when Adapter sending string parameter, it cowers it with single quotes. And result getting like

```
SELECT *
       FROM REQUESTS
       WHERE VAL IN ('12566, 13234, 244555') 
       AND STATUS NOT IN (0, 2, 9, 10)
```

And this quotes produce an error...
You can avoid this by using **SP** or bad looking and not indexed constructions like:

```
SELECT *
       FROM REQUESTS
       WHERE ',12566,13234,244555,' like '%,'||val||',%'
       AND STATUS NOT IN (0, 2, 9, 10)
```

Comment: Thanks Viktor, this looks like it might be the answer. I'll test and tick if so.

Comment: @WSC
Or event better will be create string with concatenating values (not sending as a param, bu as a part of sql string)

Comment: Yeah, that's my other thought. However I'm vary of SQL injection. I would have to make sure I correctly sanitize the input.